# Kicad PCB file gets corrupted during git merge

Tags: git, kicad

I use git to maintain all my kicad projects. Whenever I want to do a design change, I just make a new git branch and start making changes, and then later on merge it with the main.

The problem I faced is that when the merge happened, the .kicad_pcb file and the bak file were both changed in such a way that it could not be opened.

The error message read “Missing ( at line 8, in the .kicad_pcb file”.

I have two questions,

Do people use git to maintain kicad projects?
How do I merge branches locally using git on the current kicad project without corrupting the main files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by the automatic merge algorithm.

You should use `git merge --no-commit`, review (accept/reject) changes, and then commit them by `git commit` (no comment required here).

Comment: Thanks for the input, I did not think of merging branches without commit. Should work well and not corrupt the PCB file (.kicad_pcb).